# How to make this table fit nicely into one page of beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer, tabularx

```
\begin{table}[ht]

\caption{Using Quasi-Experimental Variation}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}

\hline

\hline
 & & Is the Good Rival in Consumption?: (Yes)

  & Is the Good Rival in Consumption?: (No)
\\

\hline

Is the Good Excludable?
 &  (Yes)
 & Private good (ice cream)
 & Impure public good (TV streaming)
 \\
\hline 
Is the Good Excludable?
& (No)
 &
Impure public good (crowded city sidewalk)
 & Pure public good (national defense)

\\
\hline

\hline 

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{table}
```

---

[image]

For example, like the location I used the arrow to demonstrate.
To move the "Is the Good Excludable" in front of third and fourth row.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use `table` and `center` environments. There's no point in using `table` and `figure` environments in a `beamer` document since the environments don't "float" (in the Latex sense of the word).
- Don't use `\caption`. Instead, move its argument to the argument of `\frametitle`.
- Use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, and allow line-wrapping in the two data columns.
- Combine the first two columns, and provide more structure to the header row and the first column. Essentially, avoid repeating the questions `Is the Good Rival in Consumption?` and `Is the Good Excludable?`
- Load the `booktabs` package and use its line-drawing macros in place of `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[2]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Using Quasi-Experimental Variation}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} % default: 6pt    
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} cCC @{}}
\toprule
 Is the Good Excludable? 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Is the Good Rival in Consumption?}\\
 \cmidrule(l){2-3}
 & Yes & No \\ 
\midrule
 Yes
 & Private good (ice~cream) & Impure public good (TV streaming) \\ 
\addlinespace
 No
 & Impure public good (crowded city sidewalk) & Pure public good (national defense) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request. Here are two alternative solutions, which both place the string "Is the Good Excludable" in a column by itself on the far-left, while allowing line-breaking in that column. The first alternative uses full-width rules, and the second employs rules that span columns 3 and 4 only. (Many thanks to @vonbrand for leaving a comment that suggested the second alternative!)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,multirow}
% define a centered, variable-width version of the 'X' column type:
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash%
        \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Excludable?} % measure width of first col.

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Using Quasi-Experimental Variation}

%%% First alternative solution: rules span full width of the text block
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
    >{\raggedright}p{\mylen} c C{1.1} C{0.9} @{}}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Is the Good Rival in Consumption?}\\
 \cmidrule(l){3-4}
 & & Yes & No \\
\midrule
 \multirow{3}{=}{Is the Good Excludable?}
 & Yes
 & Private good (ice~cream) 
 & Impure public good (TV streaming) \\ \addlinespace
 & No
 & Impure public good (crowded city sidewalk) 
 & Pure public good (national defense) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip\medskip
%%% Second alternative solution: rules span only columns 3 and 4
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
    >{\raggedright}p{\mylen} c C{1.1} C{0.9} @{}}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l){3-4}
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Is the Good Rival in Consumption?}\\
 \addlinespace %
 & & Yes & No \\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){3-4}
 \multirow{3}{=}{Is the Good Excludable?}
 & Yes
 & Private good (ice~cream) 
 & Impure public good (TV streaming) \\ \addlinespace
 & No
 & Impure public good (crowded city sidewalk) 
 & Pure public good (national defense) \\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l){3-4}
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, excellent. I want to modify the table a little bit. how can I move "Is the Good Excludable" in front of third and fourth row? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I showed you the location I wanted to move to below.

Comment: @user149250 - Please see the addendum I post a short while ago.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate.

Comment: I'd forget the line under the column header (for symmetry with the side "header").

Comment: @vonbrand - Many thanks for this suggestion. I've updated the answer to add a solution that shows how it might be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `\resizebox` around your tabular, if you import the graphicx package:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

......

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}
     {\begin{tabular{lccc}

      .......

      \end{tabular}
      }
```

[image]

Comment: If one recommends using `\resizebox`, one should automatically be willing to hand out magnifying glasses too...

Comment: Thank you very much! But I wanted the table in the middle of table with multiple lines in each cell. is that possible? Much appreciated.